# how to bypass E_STRICT error in php

Tags: php, error-handling, error-logging, error-log

I have a class that extends another class and override one of its methods
i want the child method to have different arguments than the parent method

i know this will trigger `E_STRICT` error in PHP

how to avoid this error without changing the method arguments? and without using "func_get_args" .. modifying the parent class is impossible

```
Class A{
    function x($a,$b=1,$c=2){}
}

Class B extends A{
    function x($a){return parent::x($a,1,2);}
}
```

Comment: One does not bypass `E_STRICT`. Instead you fix your code, so that it does not break [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Comment: but i have to add unwanted operators fot the child class